# Why doesn't $σ_xσ_p$ change with the width of the well in the infinite square well problem (intuition)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, boundary-conditions

I calculated that the product of the uncertainty in position $\sigma_x$ for the ground state of an infinite square well of width $L$ with the uncertainty in the momentum $\sigma_p$ for the same state, and it does not change with respect to the width of the well $L$. Intuitively, why does this happen?

(I would also like to know what the physical reasons are for the decrease in the momentum uncertainty, but I have [asked that separately](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/decrease-of-uncertainty-of-momentum-with-increase-of-width-of-infinite-well-in-q).)

Comment: Why would you expect it to? Neither the position nor the momentum operator know anything about the potential. Actually, why should the uncertainty of a single one of these operators depend on the potential? It depends *on the states you evaluate them on*, not on the potential.

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes, you are right! That's one way to see it. Thank you. Although i also want to see an answer that addresses the fact that with a wider well, we in general can superimpose more eigenstates.

Comment: The state actually _does_ change in this case. It becomes wider (in space). The uncertainty will depend on the potential, because the state will depend on the potential... All this is, of course, due to the assumption of ground state, which is not stated (no pun intended) in the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind and didn't we "force" the results of the potential on the wave function by plugging in the boundary conditions?

Comment: @safkan I am talking about the classic infinite well problem with ground state equal to (πhbar/L)^2/(2m) where L is the width and m is the mass.

Comment: So is the question now really "Why does $\sigma_p$ decrease as the well is made wider?"?

Comment: @DanielSank well, no. I think that it might lead to this, but i am not sure really if that is what lies at the heart of the question.

Comment: Well, you said you understand why the uncertainty in the position goes up, so that only leaves understanding why the uncertainty in momentum goes down, right? Or perhaps you want to know why the increase in $\sigma_x$ and the decrease in $\sigma_p$ exactly balance... is that it?

Comment: @DanielSank No, i just don't understand why the product of the uncertainties remains a constant AND why the uncertainty in the momentum decreases. I just think the two questions are connected.

Comment: Ok, got it. Yeah, these are connected, but actually I think both questions deserve enough detail that they deserve independent posts.

Comment: @DanielSank i might post the other question also, but i want to wait and see the answers to this first!

Comment: This is advice based on what I see happen on this site, take it or leave it: post the most specific limited question you can in each post. The more (related) questions you ask in a post the less likely you are to get an answer. If the probability that a given user will read, understand, think about, come up with an answer for, and type up that answer for a question is 1%, then the probability they'll do that for *two* questions in the same post is one in ten thousand. I could answer one of the questions here, but not both, so I haven't posted an answer because it would be incomplete.

Comment: @DanielSank I followed your advice! Cheers

Comment: Nice. This is now a much more accessible problem. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there really isn't all that much going on here beyond the fact that you're scaling the entire system, and the fact that the momentum is a derivative,
$$p=-i\hbar\frac d{dx},$$
or, alternatively, that the commutator
$$[x,p]=i\hbar$$
is fixed, means that if you rescale $x$ by some amount $\lambda$ then you need to rescale $p$ by the reciprocal of that, $1/\lambda$. The uncertainties in both operators are tied to the operators themselves in terms of scaling, so their product must remain constant under such a scaling transformation.

Comment: So this works for any potential? If I take a 1D Schrodinger equation and scale the $x$ axis does $\sigma_x \sigma_p$ always stay constant?

Comment: For the ground state, yes. (Also for any definite eigenstate. But you can't just specify the transformation of the potential without saying what happens to the wavefunction.)

Comment: The explanation is correct, but again, it's kind of mathematical. It offers no explanation based on intuition.

Comment: That *is* the intuition. Momentum scales like a wavevector because of de Broglie's relation, and that completely constrains its behaviour under scaling. You're doing very little to the system (heck, from a passive-transformation viewpoint you're doing nothing at all beyond changing your unit system) so you cannot expect the physics to change. I don't know what you were expecting but there's seriously nothing much there.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty i have found an explanation that goes like this: the narrower the well, the more confined the particle is, so it bounces off the walls of the well constantly, thus having big uncertainty. So, i guess i was looking something like this as an explanation. I agree with you that your explanation is intuitive and informative, but i was looking for a more layman approach to it. Also, could you please provide me with any sources for transformations and things like the arguments that you provided in the answer? Because i like this approach, it is very powerful