# Decrease of uncertainty of momentum with increase of width of infinite well in QM(intuition)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Why does the uncertainty in the momentum decrease with the increase of the width for an energy eigenstate in the classic problem if the infinite well in Quantum Mechanics? I have worked out the mathematics but i have not intuitively understood it.

Comment: Are you asking for an intuitive explanation of the uncertainty principle?...

Comment: @lemon no no, i am just asking why does the uncertainty in the momentum decreases. I am not at all referring to the uncertainty in the position

Comment: But this *is* essentially the uncertainty principle. A wider well means more uncertainty in position which corresponds to a narrower Fourier spectrum. And since position and momentum are Fourier transforms of each other, the momentum uncertainty decreases. ...I'm not really sure what sort of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @lemon yeah i thought about that also, but that is like cheating, because i want to be in a position as to predict the behavior of each uncertainty without invoking the uncertainty principle and then using the uncertainty principle in order to confirm my intuition. For example, i know by my intuition that the uncertainty in the position will increase with the increase of the width because there are simply more places for the quanta to be found in. But i can't use the same reasoning to predict the behavior of the uncertainty of the momentum

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240139/2451

Answer (score 1):

The momentum uncertainty $\sigma_p=\hbar \sigma_k$ decreases because the wavevector uncertainty $\sigma_k$ decreases, and $\sigma_k$ decreases because the different wavevector components of the state come closer together as the wavelengths of the corresponding components get bigger when you scale up the system. That is to say, this effect is purely to do with how the scaling behaviour works for the momentum operator.

It is tempting to think that $\sigma_x$ increases when the width $L$ of the well grows, because

> there are simply more positions for the [particle] to be found in

but that's completely misleading: there are not "more" positions - there's just an interval of relevant positions, and the *length* of this interval increases.

Similarly, in momentum space the wavefunction has a certain decomposition in terms of plane waves of definite wavelength, and when you rescale the system everything scales together: the structure of the decomposition stays constant, but the wavelengths assigned to each component will increase. If you have a given wavelength $\lambda_0$ below which the plane-wave components become negligible (by some arbitrary but definite criterion), and you scale the system by a factor $s$, then this wavelength will increase to $\lambda_0'=s\lambda_0$, and the corresponding momentum will decrease to 
$$p_o'=\frac{h}{\lambda_0'}=\frac{h}{s\lambda_0}=\frac{p_0}{s}.$$
Thus, the entire momentum structure will scale down by $1/s$, and this includes the momentum uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

Because the uncertainty in position increases. A narrower well decreases $\sigma_x$, necessarily increasing $\sigma_p$. We know $\sigma_x$ is at most $L$, so if $\sigma_p$ did not decrease, then taking $L\rightarrow 0$ would violate the uncertainty principle, since $\sigma_p$ would be nondecreasing and $\sigma_x\rightarrow 0$. More mathematically, the eigenstates in position are given by $\psi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$, so:

$$\sigma_x^2 = \left<x^2\right>-\left<x\right>^2 =\int_0^L \frac{2}{L} x^2 \sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx-\left(\int_0^L \frac{2}{L} x \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx\right)^2=\frac{n^2\pi^2-6}{12n^2\pi^2}L^2,$$

and for momentum,

$$\sigma_p^2 = \left<p^2\right>-\left<p\right>^2 = \int_0^L \left(\frac{2\hbar}{L}\right)^2 \sin^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)-0=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{L^2}.$$

Of course, $\sigma_p$ should scale inversely with $\sigma_x$, else you could generally force a limit that would violate the uncertainty principle.

Comment: Yes, but that does not provide intuition behind the reason the decrease. I mean, for the position we know that the increase of the width means that there are simply more positions for the quanta to be found in, so we intuitively expect the uncertainty in the position to increase with the increase of the width. But, how can we follow a similar reasoning for the uncertainty in the momentum without looking it mathematically(or looking it mathematically and trying to explain it more intuitively?

Comment: You can't really properly explain this without using math, but if you want a very contrived intuitive explanation, I would say that you can think of it like this: $\sigma_x$ asks the question "where is the particle in the box", so it makes sense it should scale with $L$. $\sigma_p$ basically asks the question "how many nodes can we fit in this box", which should be constant with $L$, and since $p\propto\frac{1}{L}$, then $\sigma_p\propto\frac{1}{L}\cdot \text{constant}$. If you could elaborate on where you are confused I might be able to supply a better intuitive explanation.

Comment: But why do we ask how many nodes can we fit in the box in order to talk about momentum? I mean, the momentum can stay the same(same wavelength) even when we change the width of the box. This will change the number of nodes but the wavelength is still the same. I think that the uncertainty changes from one eigenstate to another and due to the width. These are two separate things. We should isolate the effect that the change of the width has on the uncertainty(that is, to keep the mode the same--n=m)

Answer (score 0):

If the width changes, then the uncertainty in the position changes in an analogous way. No need to explain that.
For the uncertainty in the momentum now, consider a ball bouncing off of two walls when you shoot it at one of them. If the walls are very close together, the ball will bounce back and forth changing its direction rapidly. So, if the walls are far apart, the uncertainty decreases because the bouncing doesn't happen that often.